# Sobrescribir elemento html en ASPNET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cshtml

Tengo el siguiente componente de vista

```
@model IEnumerable<Folder.Models.Location>

@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
  <option value="@item.IdLocation">@item.LocationName</option>
}
```

Que me devuelve una lista con lugares

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "LocationList")]
public class LocationList : ViewComponent {
    private LocationService _LocationService = new LocationService(); 
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync() => View(await _LocationService.GetLocationsAsync()); 
}
```

El componente lo llamo desde una vista

```
  <div class="col-sm" >
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="select_provincia">Provincia</label>
      </div>
      <select class="custom-select" id="select_provincia" name="sortOrder" onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" >
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("LocationList")
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="select_canton">Canton</label>
      </div>
      <select class="custom-select" id="select_canton" name="sortOrder">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Código del evento:

```
function SelectedIndexChanged()  
{  
    var container = document.getElementById("select_canton");
    $("#select_canton").load(@await Component.InvokeAsync("LocationList"));
}
```

Entonces mi idea es que cada vez que el usuario cambie de opción en la lista de provincias, la lista de cantones se actualice. La lista de provincias carga bien el problema es cuando intento cargar los cantones.

Lo que se genera cuando se llama al evento.

```
        var container = document.getElementById("select_canton");
        $("#select_canton").load(
  <option value="1">San Jose;</option>
  <option value="2">Alajuela</option>
  <option value="3">Cartago</option>
  <option value="4">Heredia</option>
  <option value="5">Guanacaste</option>
  <option value="6">Puntarenas</option>
  <option value="7">Limon</option>
);
```

¿Hay alguna manera de sobrescribir el elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que observo es que estas definiendo un `componente` y este de por si no es dinamico (es un componente del lado del servidor) que vaya a invocarse en el `onchange` de javacript y cambiar su contenido segun la seleccion

[Populate (Bind) DropDownList using jQuery AJAX and JSON in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-DropDownList-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

[Creating Simple Cascading DropDownList In MVC 4 Using Razor](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/)

En ambos ejemplos veras como en el evento del cambio de seleccion de un combo debes realizar una llamada `$.ajax` para obtener el `json` que usaras para generar los `<option>` del combo

Presta atencion cuando usa

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
        $.each(response, function () {
            ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

eso es justamente lo que tienes que haces en el `onchange`, ir al `action` del `controller` para que retorne un `json`

Con la respuesta `json` la iteras con codigo javascript y generas los options del segundo combo